# How to force sequence of updates in DB

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have this table:

```
old_id integer NOT NULL,
new_id integer
```

Now I want to update `new_id` with a sequence in such a way that the order of `old_id` is preserved. Basically:

```
update table
set new_id = sequence.NEXTVAL
order by old_id
```

Is something like this possible? If it matters, I'm on Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update (select * from mytable order by old_id) set new_id = mysequence.nextval;
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Finally a way to update more than a single table in one go!